# Не получается работать с библиотекой pyautogui

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

В pycharm, во встроенном терминале, активировал виртуальную среду и установил библиотеку `pyautogui` через команду `pip3 install pyautogui`. После запустил файл на выполнение и мне вернулась ошибка:

```
NOTE: You must install tkinter on Linux to use MouseInfo. Run the following: sudo apt-get install python3-tk python3-dev
```

Я выполнил указанную команду, но при следующем запуске файла ничего не изменилось, что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка гласит: Вы должны установить tkinter на Linux, чтобы использовать MouseInfo. Напишите в терминал следующее: sudo apt-get install python3-tk python3-dev, после чего переустановите библиотеку